# Using more than one time input in the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
time_selection_1 = input.time(timestamp("Jun 01 2023 10:00:00 UTC+3"), 'Date/Time')
time_selection_2 = input.time(timestamp("Jun 02 2023 10:00:00 UTC+3"), 'Date/Time')

var bool highlight_date = na

if time_selection_1 == time 
    highlight_date := true 
else 
    highlight_date := false

if time_selection_2 == time 
    highlight_date := true 
else 
    highlight_date := false
```

All of the selected date/time in the input dialog needs to be highlighted in the chart. Currently, the first `time_selection_1` is highlighted but the second `time_selection_2` is not shown in the chart. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the flag.

Just go from top to bottom and you will see.

You first check if it is `time_selection_1`. If it is, then you set your flag to `true`. But then you check if it is `time_selection_2`. And if it is not, you set your flag to `false`. So, you modify your flag twice in an execution.

You can just use two different variables and `or` them.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

time_selection_1 = input.time(timestamp("Jun 01 2023 10:00:00 UTC+3"), 'Date/Time')
time_selection_2 = input.time(timestamp("Jun 02 2023 10:00:00 UTC+3"), 'Date/Time')

var is_sel_1 = false
var is_sel_2 = false

if time_selection_1 == time 
    is_sel_1 := true 
else 
    is_sel_1 := false

if time_selection_2 == time 
    is_sel_2 := true 
else 
    is_sel_2 := false

highlight_date = is_sel_1 or is_sel_2

bgcolor(highlight_date ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)
```

[image]

Comment: It does not highlight anything. Did you test the code?

Comment: Yes, I did. See the attached screenshot.